# Noise Texture becoming way detailed - Blender Guru donut tutorial

Tags: texturing

I've started following the blender donut tutorial and have hit a snag. I'm onto the texturing part of the tutorial (part 7) and I've noticed that my noise texture is becoming really really detailed.

As you can see in this picture, his donut with the noise texture looks normal and regular, but when I do the exact same thing (see next image)
[image: blender guru's donut]

Mine ends up looking like white noise and has no texture what so ever. If there are any details I need to include please let me know, as this is my first time on this form. Thank you for any help.
[image]

Comment: The scale of your donut is probably too small or too large, so you need to adjust the scale value of the noise texture accordingly.  Try setting the scale up or down a fair bit.  I didn't post this as an answer as I am somewhat guessing and haven't explained why or other ways to fix it and all that, but give it a go and see if it helps.

Comment: ... related.. try Ctrl-A, > Apply Scale